# How to get TotalRows Count in Breezejs, so that I can do paging

Tags: breeze

I am using Breezejs for client JavaScript. I am not sure how to get the Total count of query when using Breezejs (server side using IQueryable) that has filters (where clause) applied.

Comment: @NS - If you think the new "inlineCount" feature in Breeze satisfies your question, please click the checkmark under Jay's answer in which he announces that "inlineCount" is part of Breeze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of v 0.75.1 we have added a new 'inlineCount' method to the EntityQuery. Please see the breeze API docs for more details.  Hopefully, this will provide what you need.

Comment: Woo-hoo!

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_inlineCount

Answer (score 2):

We made a little change to Ward's solution, because Enumerable.Count loads all records from db, not only count (we realized this after watching sql profiler).

First we create a wrapper for IQueryable.Count extension method (because we cannot call an extension method via reflection).

```
public static class QueryWrapper {
    public static int Count<T>(IQueryable<T> query) where T: class {
        return query.Count();
    }
}
```

and we changed

```
if (actionExecutedContext.Request.RequestUri.Query.Contains("$inlinecount")) {
    if (dQuery is IQueryable) {
        inlineCount = Enumerable.Count(dQuery);
    }
}
```

with this code,

```
if (actionExecutedContext.Request.RequestUri.Query.Contains("$inlinecount")) {
    if (dQuery is IQueryable) {
        var method = typeof(QueryWrapper).GetMethod("Count");
        var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(elementType);
        inlineCount = (int)genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { dQuery });
    }
}
```

after this change, Entity Framework gets only count, not all records.

Hope this helps.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I must go back and add that to my hack. Better yet, we should get it into the product :)

Comment: Now available as part of breeze with v 0.75.1.  In the source you might note the change from Enumerable.Count(dQuery) -> Queryable.Count(dQuery), which accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Support $inlinecount in queries](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3273039-support-inlinecount-in-queries) currently is under review - please vote for it.

Comment: Your voice was heard and we're currently working on it. This should be available shortly (days).

Comment: Your voice was heard and it is in Breeze as of v 0.75.1

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: $inlineCount is in Breeze as of v.0.75.1, rendering this answer obsolete.

Accordingly, I have deleted my answer which described a workaround (a workaround improved by Umut Özel in his answer here). The new feature was driven by this S.O. question and all of your contributions. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ward, I have added our little change as an answer. Thanks for this hack btw, it works like a charm.

Comment: Ward why did you deleted the workaround it is always nice to have the solutions

Comment: I deleted it because I promised to delete it once Breeze added the inlineCount feature. Why confuse people with a workaround? Btw, my workaround didn't conform precisely to the OData spec.